# Mutable str class extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, overriding

I've written the following extension of the class str (built-in) in order to do the following operation: Suppose I have the string `"Ciao"`, by doing `"Ciao" - "a"` I want as a result the string `"Cio"`. Here it is the code that do this and it works fine:

```
class my_str(str):
   def __sub__(self, other):
       p = list(other)
       l = ""
       for el in self:
           if (el in p) == False:
               l += el

       return my_str(l)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = my_str("Ciao")
    p = my_str("a")
    t = s - p
    print(t) # 'Cio'
    print(s) # 'Ciao'
```

Now, suppose that I'd like the function `__sub__` to directly update the object `s`, in such a way that when I type `print(s)` after having execute `s - p` the output would be "Cio". How do I have to modify the class `my_str`?

Comment: The problem is that strings are immutable, you would have to make a class `mut_str` which has a `my_str` as attribute and then change that attribute - I think. Either that, or some heavy modification of the `str` internals. Interesting question.

Comment: This is impossible at the Python level - strings are immutable, so all operations that change them return new strings. It would be *possible* to do this (I think) using ctypes or cffi to call the Python C API, but it's fiddly and dangerous. Basically it's a pretty bad idea. Why do you think you need to do it? There might be better ways to do what you want.

Comment: I was only interested to do this kind of thing in general, not to solve a specific problem. If I want for example to extend the method `sort` of class `list` how do I manage to do? Do I have the same problem?

Comment: @Matteo no, lists are mutable, `a = [1,3,2]; a.sort()` will mutate `a` without problems.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
from collections import UserString  
class Test(UserString):
    def __add__(self, other):
        self.data = self.data + other
```

The `UserString` class is meant for subclassing the built-in string, and gives you the actual content as a `self.data` field.

Comment: Just to note, to flesh out the class, you'll want to use a good name like `MutableStr`, and add a `__repr__` method